# recv() 502 bad gateway -Nginx +PHP7.4-fpm, Google Cloud ubuntu instance

Tags: nginx, fpm, php-7.4

I got 502 bad gateway same issue on php7.4-fpm:

```
*3459 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response
 header from upstream, client: {ip address}, server: {xxx.zzz.com}, request: "GET /xxx/yyy HTTP/1.1", up
stream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock:", host: "{xxx.zzz.com}"
```

I run this server on google cloud VM instance nginx env.
Please let me know how can I fix this issue.
Thank you

Comment: This same behaivor is solved in the next link:
https://serverfault.com/questions/543999/nginx-errors-recv-failed-104-connection-reset-by-peer-while-reading-respon/782128

Comment: This issue is solved in the next link:
https://serverfault.com/questions/543999/nginx-errors-recv-failed-104-connection-reset-by-peer-while-reading-respon/782128

Comment: Hi @GerardoL., Thanks for your comment, I already tried with the link but there are some issues. 
Please help me if someone knows about this issue. 
Thank you